# Can a UK landlord impose additional restrictions on which documents are acceptable for right-to-rent checks?

Tags: united-kingdom, landlord, rent

landlords in the uk (edit: england) are required to carry out right-to-rent checks before renting to someone. one way these can be done is by using identifying documents from the prospective tenants. there are three lists of valid documents (which can be found e.g. [here](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/6220979ce90e0710c30a477d/RTR_Code_of_Practice_GOV.UK_version_March_2022.pdf), starting on page 20):

- list A group 1, of which only one is needed to show right to rent
- list A group 2, of which two distinct documents are required
- list B, of which only one is required but the check has to repeated at a later date

i started renting recently (the situation has now been resolved). the landlord's agent told us that they could only accept either a passport (list A group 1) or the combination of a birth certificate (list A group 2) and driving license (list A group 2), and not, for instance, a different pair of group 2 documents. is it permitted for them to make the requirements stricter than legally necessary in this way?

in trying to research this myself, it seems that the right to rent checks are legally required, but usually described as establishing a statutory excuse for the landlord in the event that it transpires the tenant doesn't actually have the right to rent, since the landlord would otherwise be liable for permitting them to do so.

Comment: It seeems a bit harsh to insist that if you don't have a list A group 1 doc such as passport then you *must* have  a driver's licence. Genuine citizens may have neither. So in a way, it could be seen as a form of discrimination.

Comment: Note that Right to Rent only applies in England, and not in the rest of the UK. https://www.gov.uk/check-tenant-right-to-rent-documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Probably.**

Firstly, note that Right to Rent [only applies in England](https://www.gov.uk/check-tenant-right-to-rent-documents), and not in the rest of the UK.

This is a bit of a strange question, because the purpose of the Right to Rent scheme is to make landlords responsible for ensuring that they only let to tenants who have a right to rent in England.

If it turns out that the tenant does not have this right, and the landlord is unable to prove that they followed the correct procedure, then the landlord is [subject to a fine and/or imprisonment](https://www.gov.uk/penalties-illegal-renting).

Therefore, it is in a landlord's interest to make the process as straightforward as possible - by accepting any document that he is legally allowed to accept. Doing otherwise would artificially restrict the number of potential tenants that could rent the property.

Of course, if there is a lot of interest in a property, then a landlord could opt to make things harder for potential tenants, by trying to dissuade those who could lead to extra paperwork for the landlord.

So could a landlord only accept a subset of the permitted documents? Probably.